# How can I convert the incoming data in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, laravel-8

I have data from Algolia in my project. Within this data, there is a `seconds` data that comes in the form of an `array`.

This is how I get this seconds data from Algolia:

```
@if(isset($content['length']))
<div class="flex items-center space-x-6">
   <div class="flex items-center">
      <img src="/assets/images/icon-clock-black.svg" alt="">
      <span  id="time" value="{{ $content['length'] }}" class="text-sm md:text-base leading-6 font-normal ml-1">{{ $content['length'] }}hrs</span>
   </div>
   <div class="flex items-center">
      <img src="/assets/images/icon-list-black.svg" alt="">
      <span  class="text-sm md:text-base leading-6 font-normal ml-1">{{ $content['lectures_count'] }} Lessons</span>
   </div>
</div>
@endif
```

**In the above code, I get this seconds data in `{{ $content['length']}}`.**

The data from Algolia is as follows. However, the **length** part of this data varies according to each content.

```
{
  "id": 99,
  "user_id": 613,
  "isLearnBite": 0,
  "name": "Write the Brand Strategy of Your Business",
  "cover": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/courses/99/images/cover/513230_1642578467.jpg",
  "color": "#fefefe",
  "description": "Many solopreneurs struggle to clarify their business strategy and marketing goals because they can't define who they are and what they offer as a brand. With this mini-course, you will be able to understand the basics of branding and write yourself a brand strategy document which will help you make a solid start and stay on your track for long years.",
  "short_description": "A solid, strategic start for your small business or start-up.",
  "length": 6783,
  "order": 0,
  "status_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2022-01-18T07:14:42.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-01-19T12:48:29.000000Z",
  "custom_fields": {
    "dynamic_link": "https://omnicourse.page.link/cC8bZNQ6WhU1ahGS9"
  },
  "lectures_count": 27,
  "lecturer_name": "Nil Yalcinkaya",
  "lecturer_username": "nile_brand_academy",
  "lecturer_avatar": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/creator_thumbnail/613/2022-03-29/thumbnail_400X400_985347_1638513165.jpg",
  "tags": [
    30,
    43,
    150,
    206
  ],
  "categories": [
    2
  ],
  "last_listened_data": null,
  "user_rating": 0,
  "isFavorited": false,
  "isBookMarked": false,
  "isCompleted": false,
  "creator_profile": {
    "name": "Nil Yalcinkaya",
    "username": "nile_brand_academy",
    "avatar": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/creator_thumbnail/613/2022-03-29/thumbnail_400X400_985347_1638513165.jpg",
    "about": "Hi! \r\nI write brand strategies for digital start-ups of the future and design their visual brand identities. \r\nSee My Services: Nile Brand Design\r\nFollow & Join Our Community to Learn More about Branding: Nile Brand Academy",
    "custom_fields": {
      "email_octopus_id": "bc6ec095-69ec-11ec-96e5-06b4694bee2a",
      "email_octopus_last_update": "2022-03-26 00:48:58",
      "avatar_thumb_400*400": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/creator_thumbnail/613/2022-03-29/thumbnail_400X400_985347_1638513165.jpg",
      "linkedin": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/nilyalcinkaya/",
      "instagram": "https://www.instagram.com/nile.brand.design/",
      "twitter": "https://twitter.com/nilsyalcinkaya",
      "website": "https://www.nilebrand.design/"
    }
  },
  "_tags": [
    "App\\Course::99"
  ],
  "objectID": "App\\Course::99"
}
```

I wrote a **JS** code like below to print this length data in **hour minute seconds** format, but I guess I'm doing something wrong, it didn't work.

```
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function secondsToHms(d) {
            var d = getElementById("time").value;
            var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
            var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
            var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

            var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour, " : " hours, ") : "";
            var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute, " : " minutes, ") : "";
            var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " second" : " seconds") : "";
            return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
        }

    </script>
@endsection
```

Also, when I call this function, I get a "call undefined function" error. I would be very grateful if you could help me with that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `secondsToHms` function you are passing a variable called `d` as a function param and you're also declaring a variable `d` in the next line - you can't do that. I've tested that code and it works:

```js
function secondsToHms(d) {
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour, " : " hours, ") : "";
    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute, " : " minutes, ") : "";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " second" : " seconds") : "";
    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
}

console.log(secondsToHms(500));
console.log(secondsToHms(5000));
console.log(secondsToHms(12571243));
```

Comment: So how can I use this function in `{{ $content['length'] }}` ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with that syntax so I can't help you here. You should be able to call that function with a param of your choice but as I said this syntax means nothing to me right now.